# Problems with while loop on XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, xpathnodeiterator

I am trying to while loop on an XPathNodeIterator object

```
     XPathNodeIterator xpCategories = GetCategories().Current.Select("/root/category/id");
```

now xpCategories holds an xml like this

```
 <root>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>format</id>
    <name>Kopi/Print</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="1">
    <id>frankering</id>
    <name>Kopi/Print</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>gardbøjler</id>
    <name>Møbler</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>gardknager</id>
    <name>Møbler</name>
  </category>
  <category numberofproducts="0">
    <id>gardspejle</id>
    <name>Møbler</name>
  </category>

</root>
```

And I need to get each of the category nodes "id" inside the loop.tried some thing like this

```
XPathNodeIterator xpCategories = GetCategories().Current.Select("/root/category/id");    
while (xpCategories.MoveNext())
Console.WriteLine(xpCategories.Current.Value);
```

But this loop works only one time after that it exits.I can't understand what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
while (xpCategories.MoveNext())
{
    XPathNavigator n = xpCategories.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
}
```

OR

```
foreach (XPathNavigator n in xpCategories)Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
```

---

Though I would recommend LINQ2XML

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
List<string> ids=doc.Elements("category")
                    .Select(x=>x.Element("id").Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried your first and second method ,The same problem I have explained in the question still exists.And as I am fetching the XML from a third party API I can't uses Document doc=XDocument.Load(xmlPath); .(there will be no path to give)